# Can't figure out how to get transparency on output .mov file

Tags: python, transparency, alpha

I'm a graphic designer at a media company and want to build a nametitle generator. The thing is, I want the titles to be animated, so Ive made an animation in after effects and rendered this as a `.mov` file with an alpha channel. Ive build a simple GUI where the user van input name and subtitle and than clicks a button with `''generate title''`. I now want the output file also to have transparency so the user can import te title into there editing software, but I just can figure it out. The background is always black (I import the file back in After Effects).

I using `ffmpeg` now to produce the outfile, but ive tried moviepy and pygame things as well. Nothing gives me an alpha channel. The portion of code I use now for `ffmpeg` is:

```
def generate_video():
    naam = name_entry.get()
    ondertitel = subtitle_entry.get()

    video_path = 'D:\\Werk\\NOORD\\TITELGENERATOR\\horizontaal-links.mov'
    output_path = os.path.join(base_path, "output.mov")

    # FFmpeg commando om tekst op video toe te voegen
    command = [
        'C:\\PATH_programs\\ffmpeg.exe',  # absoluut pad naar ffmpeg
        '-i', video_path,
        '-c:v', 'prores_ks',
        '-profile:v', 'hq',  # kies een ProRes-profiel
        '-bits_per_mb', '4000',  # aantal bits per macroblock
        '-alpha_bits', '16',  # 16 bits alpha channel
        '-vf', f"drawtext=text='{naam}':x=100:y=50:fontsize=24:fontcolor=white,drawtext=text='{ondertitel}':x=100:y=100:fontsize=24:fontcolor=white",
        '-y', 'output.mov'
    ]
    print("Uit te voeren commando:", ' '.join(command))  # Voor debugging

    # Uitvoeren van het FFmpeg commando
    subprocess.run(command)
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in ProRes with ffmpeg, but my understanding is you have to set the -pix_fmt option to "yuva444p10le" to utilize the 4444 colorspace, which you need for alpha transparency.  There's more info under the Prores section here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VFX